# Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s) E/flutter (17155): #0 List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:149:60)

Tags: arguments

I'm working on a chat section of my app where i want to update some fields from one collection to other in following manners;

//getting user data fields already saved in firestore with users collection.

Future getUserData ()async{

```
var data = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').getDocuments();
if (data == null){
  return CircularProgressIndicator();}
else{
  print(data.documents.length);
  setState(() {
    userData = data;
    index = index;
  });
}
```

}
//using above data in here

await DatabaseService(uid: sender.uid).setUserDataExtra(

```
  message.senderEmail,message.message, FieldValue.serverTimestamp().toString(),
  message.senderId,userData.documents[index]['userImage']==null?'':userData.documents[index]['userImage'],userData.documents[index]['fullName']==null?'':userData.documents[index]['fullName']);
```

so suppose i have 2 users in my users collection and if i replace index manually to 0 or 1 it is working fine but if i leave as it is im getting error invalid Invalid argument(s).

I also have created var index; in my main class and have tried with replacing var to final nothing works except putting index number manually.

please help:(